# Laravel 5.7 Database Design Layout / Average from Collection

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7, laravel-collection

I have a situation where each `Order` can have `Feedback.` In case the product is physical, the `Feedback` can have many `packaging_feedbacks.` The `packaging_feedbacks` are supposed to be a relation to the `packaging_feedback_details.`

**Feedback Model**

```php
public function packagingFeedbacks()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\PackagingFeedbackDetail', 'App\PackagingFeedback',
        'feedback_id', 'id', 'id', 'user_selection');
}

packaging_feedback_details
id|type_id(used to group the "names" for each feedback option)|name
1  0                                                            well packed
2  0                                                            bad packaging
3  1                                                            fast shipping
4  1                                                            express delivery

packaging_feedbacks
id|feedback_id|user_selection (pointing to the ID of packaging_feedback_details)
1   1           2
2   1           6
3   1           7
4   1           12
5   1           15
6   1           17
7   2           1
8   2           6
9   2           7
10  2           12
11  2           15
12  2           17
13  3           1
14  3           6
15  3           7
16  3           12
17  3           15
18  3           17
```

Now I would like to be able to get the average selection of the users for a physical product. I started by using:

```php
$result = Product::with('userFeedbacks.packagingFeedbacks')->where('id', 1)->first();
$collection = collect();

foreach ($result->userFeedbacks as $key) {
    foreach ($key->packagingFeedbacks as $skey) {
        $collection->push($skey);
    }
}

foreach ($collection->groupBy('type_id') as $key) {
    echo($key->average('type_id'));
}
```

But it returns not the average id since it will calculate the average not the way I need it to calculate. Is there some better way, because I think it's not the cleverest way to do so. Is my database design, in general, the "best" way to handle this?

---

Comment: When you say average id, do you mean the most common one?

Comment: @Ross Wilson
Yes, meaning the most common one, not the average from the "values" itself. I'm unsure if my way to handle the feedback is "a good one" in general.

Comment: The most common value would be `$collection->mode('type_id')`, not sure if it will work with strings instead of numbers though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of average you're looking for here is **mode**. Laravel's collection instances have a [mode()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-mode) method which was introduced in 5.2 which when provide a key returns an array containing the highest occurring value for that key.

---

If I have understood your question correctly this should give you what you're after:

```
$result->userFeedbacks
    ->flatMap->packagingFeedbacks
    ->groupBy('type_id')
    ->map->mode('id');
```

The above is taking advantage of [flatMap()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-flatmap) and [higher order messages()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#higher-order-messages) on collections.

Comment: I've updated my first post, with a bit database code, your code returns 0 as value. Did you understand what I try to archive (see database code above)?

Comment: @john_doee I have removed the `array_first` from the example in my answer which should now give you the result `[0, 1]`.

Comment: Using your code returns `array:6 [▼
  0 => 0
  1 => 1
  2 => 2
  3 => 3
  4 => 4
  5 => 5
]` which is not the result expected I think.

Comment: @john_doee Have you used the code I have in my answer exactly and then just `dd($typeIds)` straight after it? As I'm not sure how/why you would be getting multiple values from the `mode()` method. Can you show the code for your `PackagingFeedbackDetail` model?

Comment: The model itself is naked, just created it using artisan. I think the problem is the call of flatMap, isn't it? When I try to debug the code part by part it's failing, when I do: `$result = Product::with('userFeedbacks.packagingFeedbacks')->where('id', 1)->first();

        dd($result->userFeedbackss->flatMap->packagingFeedbacks);` I place the dd() directly after your code, yes.

Comment: @john_doee In the example above you have `userFeedbackss` instead of `userFeedbacks` is that just a typo in the comment or did you actually try that code?

Comment: I've got located the problem. Somehow I need to "group" the results first by using the type_id, after this I need to check every sorted "parts" one by one by the id, to get the most choosen option from a user. Did you understand?

Comment: @john_doee Yeah, I'm pretty sure I got what you're after. You want to get the most common `type_id` in the `packaging_feedback_details` bases on the `Product` you're querying?

Comment: I want to get the most choosen id from packaging_feedback_details. The user has choosen this id inside packaging_feedbacks (field user_selection) **but** the results must be grouped by the type_id first, just to make sure, the IDs are part of the current group (see packaging_feedback_details table above).

Comment: @john_doee Oh, sorry about that, I had definitely misunderstood. I'll update my answer now.

Comment: works as expected, I included a `->sortBy('type_id')` before the `->groupBy()`, just to make sure the order is as I expected it to be. Do you have any idea how to get the name attribute (packaging_feedback_details) for the "most common" selected option? For sure I could use a `PackagingFeedbackDetail($id)->name` , but is there some more efficient way to place this code inside the collection filtering itself?

Comment: @john_doee Just change `->mode('id')` to `mode->('name')` and that should do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Collections are that kind of awesome.

Comment: @john_doee Yes they are! Glad I could help.